# Change placement of 'Read more' link in a teaser

Tags: theming

I have a view where the content is displayed as teasers on the page. There is a 'Read more' link that is displayed above the body text for each teaser (refer to the screenshot below, circled in red), but I would like it to sit underneath the body text instead. Any suggestions on how this can be done?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out how to move the 'Read more' link to display below the body text for each teaser.

In my Drupal site, I went into 'Structure' in the main administration menu > 'Content types' > Selected the content type I created (in this case, it was: 'Blog post') > Manage display > and then went into the 'Teaser' tab. I was then able to move around the fields so that the 'Read more' link displayed below the body text.